# If the team captain wants to be at either end of the line, how many ways can the team members line up?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Can someone just check my answers and help me with part b please?

The volleyball team is lining up to take a yearbook photo. There are 12 team members, three of which are seniors.

**a. How many ways can the team members line up for the photo?**

$12!$

**b. If the team captain wants to be at either end of the line, how many ways can the team members line up?**

This one I'm confused about because I don't know if I'm permuting two spaces or one. Because it doesn't matter if he is at the front or the back so would it be

$11!(\frac{2!}{2!})$ or would it be 11P2

**c. If the three seniors want to stand next to each other, how many ways can the team members line up?**

$11!(\frac{3!}{3!})=11!$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

For part (b), apart from the captain, the $11$ other members can stand in $11!$ ways. For each of these $11!$ permutations, the captain can take two positions (either end of the line). So what is the total number of posibilities?

For part (c), $9$ junior members + the set of seniors can stand in $(9+1)!$ ways. Also, among themselves, the seniors can stand in $3!$ ways. So how many ways can the members line up?

Answer (score 0):

When captain is at start or end of row then there are 2×11! ways . All you did is just that you fixed captain's position from 12 places to two . $(12! = 12×11!)$

For 3rd part
Assume all three seniors as one so now there are 10 persons to rearrange so there are total $10!$ ways .
And if you take all seniors different then you can also rearrange them , so there will be $10!×3!$ ways .